# Run a javascript function when a hidden input is changed by a radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty with getting a javascript function to run once the selection of a radio button is selected.  I probably am just missing one little thing or maybe more.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Place a title here.</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js\utilities.js"></script>
    <script src="js\backgroundworker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="master">
<form action='' method="post" id="LoginForm">
        <div style='text-align: center'>
            <div><label>Please pick a poulation size: </label></div>
            <div style="width: 33%; float:left;"><label for="small">Small<input type="radio" name="PopulationSize" id="small" value="small" onclick="document.getElementById('checked_radio').value=this.value;" /></label></div>
            <div style="width: 33%; float:left;"><label for="medium">Medium<input type="radio" name="PopulationSize" id="medium" value="medium" onclick="document.getElementById('checked_radio').value=this.value;" /></label></div>
            <div style="width: 33%; float:left;"><label for="large">Large<input type="radio" name="PopulationSize" id="large" value="large" onclick="document.getElementById('checked_radio').value=this.value;" /></label></div>
            <input type="hidden" id="checked_radio" name="checked_radio" value="" />
        </div>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a standard javascript utilities to discovery and shorthand functions.

```
function Bobsalert(){
// get the value of the hidden text
var checked_radio = U.$("checked_radio");
//call alert popup
window.alert("change detected value is: "  + checked_radio);
}

window.onload = function (){

if(U.$("checked_radio") !== null) {
U.addEvent(U.$('checked_radio'),'onchange', Bobsalert);
}
}
```

Thank you ahead of time for any help on this.  I just seem to be stuck.

Comment: What about this: http://jsfiddle.net/bZj4H/1/

Comment: WOW that seems to work, I'll copy it into my html page and have a look see on the server.  This is great all I been looking for the week for a solution, and noticed i had started to copy errors into it from working on it too much.  I posted it and you had a solution in the time it took to pop my popcorn!